# How to access delta tables from azure data lake in jupyter notebook using pyspark

Tags: delta-lake

```py
spark.read.format("delta").load("/tmp/delta/people10m")
```

How to give correct path to adls delta folder?

```py
spark.read.format("delta").load("/tmp/delta/people10m")
```

tried above command, but not working

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the direct access to ADLS, then you need to give a full path, like, `abfss://<container>@<storage-acct>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>` - just following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/azure-storage#direct-access-using-abfs-uri-for-blob-storage-or-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2) about it (there are different authentication options available, so select what works for you).